# NextJS Redirect query parameter to path

Tags: next.js

I want to redirect my url from /shop?q=blabla to /shop/blabla.

My next.config.js file:

```
  {
    source: '/shop?q=:sef',
    destination: '/shop/:sef',
    permanent: true,
  },
```

doesn't work. And returns error "Reason: Unexpected MODIFIER at 7, expected END"

I also tried code below;

```
  {
    source: '/shop',
    has: [
      {
        type: 'query',
        key: 'q',
        value: '(?<paramName>.*)'
      },
    ],
    permanent: true,
    destination: '/shop/:paramName',
  },
```

and It doesnt work with no errors.

Comment: That redirect rule works for me. Did you restart the dev server after updating the `redirects` function in your `next.config.js`?